# Make select sum() not return null

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make a sql query with sum that will show me only records where sum is not null and != 0. Now I have:

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT SUM(time) AS sumToPay,
w.name, w.lname 
FROM `service` s 
JOIN worker w 
ON s.worker_id = w.id 
GROUP BY s.worker_id
```

It shows me proper sum of time but when one worker has no time it shows me 0. How to force query to show only not null values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a having clause

```
SELECT 
sum(time) as sumToPay, 
w.name, 
w.lname 
FROM `service` s 
join worker w on s.worker_id = w.id 
group by s.worker_id 
having sum(time) > 0
```

Comment: Yes, `HAVING` is like `WHERE` but operates on the resultset, not the initial data.

Comment: Thank's a lot! Woking perfectly

Comment: @Chris Glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me whether you wish to completely omit rows where the `SUM()` comes out as 0 or whether you want to see the `SUM()` of all none-null values. Donal's answer gives you the former, this should give you the latter:

```
SELECT SUM(time) AS sumToPay,
w.name, w.lname 
FROM `service` s 
JOIN worker w ON s.worker_id = w.id 
WHERE time IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY s.worker_id
```